# How to remove all newlines ("\n") between two patterns with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I try to remove newlines with a lot of commands found during my research but nothing works.

Input file:

```
<pattern>
blablabla
</pattern>
```

Wanted output:

```
<pattern>blablabla</pattern>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
bla
<pattern>
bla
bla
</pattern>
bla
[STEP 102] $ sed -e '/^<pattern>/!b' -e :a -e 'N;/\n<\/pattern>/!ba' -e 's/\n//g' file
bla
<pattern>blabla</pattern>
bla
[STEP 103] $
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk might be a better option for this:

```
 awk '/^<pattern>/ { mark=1 } /^<\/pattern>/ { mark=0 } mark==1 { printf "%s",$0 } mark==0 { printf "%s\n",$0 }' file
```

Explanation

```
awk '/^<pattern>/ { 
                    mark=1                # When we see "<pattern>" at the start of the line, set a variable mark to 1
                  } 
     /^<\/pattern>/ { 
                    mark=0                # When we see "</pattern>" at the start of the line, reset the variable mark
                   } 
           mark==1 { 
                    printf "%s",$0        # When mark is one (we are in pattern tags, print the line with no carriage return
                   } 
           mark==0 { 
                    printf "%s\n",$0      # When mark is 0, (we are out of pattern tags), print the line with a carriage return.
                   }' file
```

Comment: Hi Raman, 
not for all the file, only between <pattern> and </pattern>

Comment: OK, I've added an awk alternative

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^<[^>]+>/{:a;/<([^>]+>).*<\/\1/!{N;ba};s/\n//g}' file
```

If a line contains the pattern `<...>`, continue appending lines until a line containing its dual `</...>` and then remove all newlines.

N.B. The line containing `<...>` may also contain `</...>`, in which case the line is left unchanged.